# Create a list of strings instead of list of words

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Input Data:

```
[{"is_sarcastic": 1, "headline": "thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock of hair loss", "article_link": "https://www.theonion.com/thirtysomething-scientists-unveil-doomsday-clock-of-hai-1819586205"},
{"is_sarcastic": 0, "headline": "dem rep. totally nails why congress is falling short on gender, racial equality", "article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donna-edwards-inequality_us_57455f7fe4b055bb1170b207"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
["thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock hair loss",  
"dem rep totally nails why congress is falling short on gender racial equality"]
```

I am able to get the expected output with the subsequent code snippet.

```
stop_words = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "..."]
_corpus, _result = [], []
for text in data:
    text_clean = [word for word in re.split('\W+', text['headline'])if word.lower() not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]
    _corpus.append(' '.join(text_clean))
    _result.append(text['is_sarcastic'])
```

I was trying to make it concise, purely for learning purposes, but was unable to replicate the same result with the below listed code snippet.

```
 _corpus, _result = map(list, zip(
        *[(''.join(word), text['is_sarcastic']) for text in data for word in re.split('\W+', text['headline'])
          if word.lower() not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]))
```

I get list of words rather than strings. Ex: `['thirtysomething', 'scientists', ...]`.

I am not using the `join` method appropriately. How can I make this work?

Edit 1: My goal is to get a list of Strings instead of list of words.
Edit 2: I did not include the entire dataset since I thought it was not relevant to the problem.
Edit 3: Please ignore this post, I am having a difficult to communicate with clarity. I appreciate y'all for trying to help me.
Edit 4: Re-formatting the question.

Comment: Do you want to remove punctuation characters?

Comment: There are easier ways to remove punctuation from strings

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and supply a runnable [mcve] if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying to create a list of strings  with the following code.     
       `_corpus, _result = map(list, zip(
        *[(''.join(word), text['is_sarcastic']) for text in data for word in re.split('\W+', text['headline'])
          if word.lower() not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]))`                               For obvious reasons it does not work.

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve instead. If the code doesn't work, no one can guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't give up! Show the output that you want to achieve, and the input that you have, it would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert the following snippet into a list comprehension:

```
stop_words = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "..."]
_corpus, _result = [], []
for text in data:
    text_clean = [word for word in re.split('\W+', text['headline']) if word.lower() not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]
    _corpus.append(' '.join(text_clean))
    _result.append(text['is_sarcastic'])
```

This is not a good idea since the code is already not easy to read! You should start with a function:

```
def clean(headline):
    return [word for word in re.split('\W+', headline) if word.lower() not in stop_words and len(word) > 2]

_corpus, _result = [], []
for text in data:
    _corpus.append(' '.join(clean(text['headline'])))
    _result.append(text['is_sarcastic'])
```

If you want a list comprehension, use a single list to store pairs :

```
_ret = []
for text in data:
    _ret.append((' '.join(clean(text['headline'])), text['is_sarcastic']))
# [('thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock hair loss', 1), ('dem rep totally nails why congress falling short gender racial equality', 0)]
```

This loop will be easy to convert into a list comprehension. To get the result, `zip` the elements to recreate two tuples:

```
_corpus, _result = zip(*_ret)
# ('thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock hair loss', 'dem rep totally nails why congress falling short gender racial equality') (1, 0)
```

Or, as you did:

```
_corpus, _result = map(list, zip(*_ret))
# ['thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock hair loss', 'dem rep totally nails why congress falling short gender racial equality'] [1, 0]
```

The full code:

```
import re

stop_words = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "..."]
_ret = [(' '.join(clean(text['headline'])), text['is_sarcastic']) for text in data]
_corpus, _result = map(list, zip(*_ret))
print (_corpus, _result)
# ['thirtysomething scientists unveil doomsday clock hair loss', 'dem rep totally nails why congress falling short gender racial equality'] [1, 0]
```

Not far from what you write, but the `text['is_sarcastic']` was misplaced.

Comment: @BrokenCranium Wow! I was glad to help you *and* your faith in humanity.